# SharePoint 2010 server object model required runwithElevatedPrevileage

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I have a query that SharePoint 2010 server object model required runwithElevatedPrevileage. if suppose we not using that elevated access, what are all the restriction we will face?...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you use your code to display data from a list and it should be viewed by all the users, You need to have elevated access otherwise the restricted users will not be able to view the content for which they do not have access.